# Which events are triggered on a UAC prompt?

Tags: windows, events, directshow, uac

Are there any windows events triggered when a UAC elevation prompt is shown? I've looked at SwitchDesktop, but can't see any mention of how to receive notifications.

My direct show app is behaving badly, and I'd like to be able to pause the graph when when the prompt is displayed, resuming when dismissed.

I'm using C++ with MFC, VS2008, targetting XP, Vista and 7.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there are any events sent when UAC prompt displays. Basically it makes a screenshot of the desktop, and switches to another session where UAC prompt window is displayed. What are your symptoms? You can use the following technics: [Painting only when your window is visible on the screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/29/54728.aspx).

Comment: Given the lack of responses on here and not being able to find anything in searches, I fear you might be right. Seems a bit of an oversight to me though. My graph resets the capture file back to a zero size whenever an UAC prompt is displayed. This happens regardless of whether the application is visisble or not, so the teqnique in your linked article would not work. I have identified the VMR9 filter as the culprit though so will look into alternative renderers.

Comment: No, if there were an event notifying about UAC prompt, then it would be a security hole: applications could interfere with it. The whole idea of UAC is that applications can't overcome it and can't control it. That's weird… although I don't quite understand what you mean by *“resets the capture file back to zero size”*. Does it work normally when you call Windows Security dialog via Ctrl+Alt+Del?

Comment: I don't want to interfere or control it, and I don't see how letting applications know it's happening would be a problem, but I'm not here to argue. The capture file which is happily saving video input and increasing in size up until that point, is wiped clean when the UAC prompt is shown. It only contains video captured after the prompt. I've found posts reporting these symptoms with the VMR9 filter since windows vista, so it would appear it's not going to be fixed. I haven't tried the security dialog and unfortunately don't have access to the test system until next week. Cheers for your help

Comment: This seems to be a bug in VMR9 so I don't think you're going to get any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there are any events sent when UAC prompt displays. Basically it makes a screenshot of the desktop, and switches to another session where UAC prompt window is displayed.

Comment: Not to leave the question unanswered, converted comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This was answered in another thread here (superuser), The solution name is: UAC Auditing.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/273236/reason-for-user-account-control-dialog

**Edit for essinital part: (Summary of the URL above)**

> Uac Auditing is done by changing windows policy (Local\Group). The
>   policy in interest is found at:
>   *Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy*
>
> **Audit Privilege Use** will give you information about elevated usage using the UAC consent.exe dialog box in the System Event log. The
>   Event IDs created by this: 4648 and 4624.
>
> **Audit Process Tracking** will give you information about processes and their creation/termination. Event Id created by this: 4688.
>
> Also, look at event id 4696 to see when a new token (user-logon
>   handle) was assigned to process. Using all these events, you can get a
>   clear picture of the timeline for every process that requested an
>   elevated rights with UAC dialog.

Here is a site containig a short summary for every Event ID in the System Event log:

*Description of security events in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2*
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977519

**Edit 2**:
Not all Windows versions has a Policy editor included (like Windows 7 Home premium). However, Local Audit Policy editor  (Not Group Policy) is accesible in Windows 7 Home Premium with Auditpol.exe and on Windows XP SP2 with Auditusr.exe

For more information about using Auditpol.exe see here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a02cfb9d-732f-4e77-aeba-f18265daa3af

Comment: You should include the essential parts of the solution here, in case the link you gave goes out of date in the future.

Comment: I assumed superuser will be there as long as stackoverflow will be there. anyway, I did edit the essential for ease of read.

Answer (score 2):

When the UAC switches desktops, your graph will receive a device-lost event raised by the renderer (EC_DEVICE_LOST or something like that). You can override the default handling for this, but if you don't, the default handling will stop, disconnect and reconnect the renderer (so it can reacquire the device) and then seek to the previous position and restart. You could also put the renderer in a separate graph using a bridge, so that your capture is not interrupted.

G