# Monitor UAC occurs

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for solution to capture User Account Control occurs on clients computers. I want to develop Powershell's script and deploy  in environemnt with Active Directory 2008 and Windows 10 clients. Currently end users have full local administration rights. I need a report to check how often they're really need elevated permissions.

Regards,
Lynx

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please see [help/on-topic].

Comment: Yes, @IInspectable, Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is a programming question. Just not in your domain and language.

Comment: @NathanHartley This is clearly an administrative problem. Just because the solution *may* boil down to jotting up a few lines that PowerShell can digest into a program doesn't make it a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see when UAC Prompts are displayed, you can enable UAC Auditing on devices with a regkey or a Group Policy setting, [as covered here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292159/1238413)

> Uac Auditing is done by changing windows policy (Local\Group). The policy in interest is found at: **Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy**
>
> Audit Privilege Use will give you information about elevated usage using the UAC consent.exe dialog box in the System Event log. The Event IDs created by this: 4648 and 4624.
>
> Audit Process Tracking will give you information about processes and their creation/termination. Event Id created by this: 4688.
> Also, look at event id 4696 to see when a new token (user-logon handle) was assigned to process. Using all these events, you can get a clear picture of the timeline for every process that requested an elevated rights with UAC dialog.

Once that's done, you can audit those events in a PowerShell script by looking for the Windows Event of the appropriate ID like this:

```
$UACEvents = Get-WinEvent -LogName System | where Id -in (4648, 4624)
```

Then you simply bake that into whatever process you like.

Event Info

```
Id     Event
4624   A new account was logged in
4648   A logon was attempted using explicit credentials
4696   A primary token was assigned to process
```

Comment: OK, thank you. 
I have created simple script to add entries into CSV file on one of servers. Now I working to applly PS Workflow to increse tolerance for connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets from a similar script I am working on to detect UAC elevations on our Azure AD joined PCs, that are only supposed to be managed through Intune.

```
# Enable Auditing of Sensitive Privilege Use
auditpol.exe /set '/subcategory:{0CCE9228-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030}' /success:enable


filter ParseSPUEvent {
    $SelectorStrings = [string[]]@(
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="SubjectUserName"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="SubjectDomainName"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="SubjectUserSid"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="ProcessId"]',
        'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="ProcessName"]'
    )
    $PropertySelector = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector]::new($SelectorStrings)
    $SubjectUserName, $SubjectDomainName, $SubjectUserSid, $ProcessId, $ProcessName = $_.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)

    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        DateTime     = $_.TimeCreated
        UserName     = $SubjectUserName
        Domain       = $SubjectDomainName
        UserSid      = $SubjectUserSid
        ProcessId    = $ProcessId
        ProcessName  = $ProcessName
    } | Write-Output
}

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName = 'Security'; ID = 4673; StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | ParseSPUEvent
```