# Identify Credential prompt types in Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11, windows-credential-provider

Windows launches credential prompt for elevated access. I am trying to find a way to identify the credential prompt if it was specifically launched by / for outlook related tasks. Is there a way to identify it through powershell or by default windows tools? So, this powershell or Windows tool in the background should identify the credential prompt if it is related to outlook.

at the moment not finding resources to achieve this.

Edit:1

In the image [link], if it is prompt initiated by outlook, I see the application source of prompt is already showing up. How/where do I capture it?
[CredentialPrompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeiGJ.png)

Comment: A brief search led me to a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292159/1553090) which then referenced a [Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/273236/128815) and mentions UAC Auditing. Here is some related Microsoft documentation: [Audit Sensitive Privilege Use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-sensitive-privilege-use). Requires policy changes. Check out the whole section on auditing. As these are system events, you can presumably hook them.

Comment: You can create a dummy Credential Provider that only thing it will do is to analyze loading environment and/or conditions to found (for example) Main Executable name and compare it to "OUTLOOK.EXE". In case of match you can rise a flag or event.

Comment: Thanks for the info @paddy. This have given me good insight.
With this I am able to create new event ID and catch credentialUIbroker (Credential prompt / UAC), and in the same time duration, I am able see outlook.exe. However I dont see any link between these 2 events. Like, this credentailuibroker.exe event has been initiated by or the source app of credentailuibroker.exe

Comment: Thanks for the post @Alexander. Really appreciate if you could share more info on this please?